# How can i refresh UserControl2 from UserControl1 using Telerik?

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I have two UserControls - UserControl1.ascx and UserControl2.ascx

I have a RadGrid1 in UserControl1.ascx. 
I have a form in UserControl2.ascx.

When i update RadGrid1 in UserControl1.ascx then i want refresh data in form in UserControl2.ascx.

How can i refresh data in UserControl2 from UserControl1 using Telerik?

Answer (score 0):

Place the Two user controls inside a RadAjaxManager like this:

```
 <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID=" UserControl1">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID=" UserControl2"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
                     <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID=" UserControl1"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
                  </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

and below place your user controls after you register em on the webpage

```
<uc1:UsreControl1  ID="UserControl1" runat="server"/>

<uc2:UsreControl2  ID="UserControl2" runat="server"/>
```

Hope it will work for u as It had worked for me in my project.